# How to integrate square API in ionic/phone-gap app

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, square-connect

I am developing application using ionic.

I would like to use square payment gateway into my app but I am not able to find any plugin to support square API to integrate into my hybrid app.

Comment: Hello Manoj, did you get any solutions how to integrate square API in Ionic platform.? i want to integrate square API in my Ionic project Thanks.

Comment: No not yet done

Comment: Thank You for your answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Check out these docs for Square Payment Gateway in your apps

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios/

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios-v1.2-released-2016-11/